# How to toggle input fields in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I want to dynamically toggle (enable and disable) one or the other `<input>`.

Desired behavior: When user selects `Yes`, the first `<input>` is enabled but the second `<input>` is disabled. When user clicks `No`, vice versa.

---

Here is what I tried https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-pfacix

---

The  `Value Selected {{}}` correctly logs `true` and `false`. **So I know 100% that the boolean value is getting assigned.**

But for some reason the `attr.disabled` doesn't toggle. It only works the first time I click it only. Why ? ? ? 
I tried to use `disabled` `disable` `attr.disable` I tried all variations

Comment: You can use `[disabled]` set to `true` or `false` instead of `[attr.disabled]`.

Comment: Thank you . I added Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-pfacix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beauty of reactive forms is you can catch values changes event of any input element very easily and at the same time you can change their values/ status. So here is the way to tackle your problem.

Subscribe to value changes event of `yesNoToggle` field and enable disable the input fields based upon the value

```
subscribeYesNoToggle() {
    this.SignupForm.get('yesNoToggle').valueChanges.subscribe(data => {

      if (data === 'false') {
        this.SignupForm.get('mustToggle1').disable();
        this.SignupForm.get('mustToggle2').enable();
      } else{
        this.SignupForm.get('mustToggle2').disable();
        this.SignupForm.get('mustToggle1').enable();
      }
    })
  }
```

Here is the complete solution on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-53925391?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you. It works. I just thought it could be solved with a simple directive `[disable]="yesNoToggle.getValue` somthing like this. without creating a function to handle it. I thought angular was supposed to simplify these extra code. Otherwise, it could be done with a bootstrap toggle or simple js. No need to use typescrip at all